# Keeping returned records from mysql unique

Tags: mysql, left-join

Is there a quick way to make sure the records you return from a MySQL JOIN query are unique?

The code below could potentially bring back the same category twice.  Its the category ID which should be distinct!

```
SELECT 
   exp_categories.cat_name, exp_categories.cat_id, exp_categories.cat_url_title
  ,exp_category_posts.entry_id, exp_channel_titles.status 
FROM (exp_categories 
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts 
       ON exp_categories.cat_id = exp_category_posts.cat_id) 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles 
       ON exp_category_posts.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_categories.group_id = 2 
  AND exp_category_posts.entry_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND exp_channel_titles.status = 'open' 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
   exp_categories.cat_name, exp_categories.cat_id, exp_categories.cat_url_title
  ,exp_category_posts.entry_id, exp_channel_titles.status 
FROM (exp_categories 
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts 
       ON exp_categories.cat_id = exp_category_posts.cat_id) 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles 
       ON exp_category_posts.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_categories.group_id = 2 
  AND exp_category_posts.entry_id IS NOT NULL 
  AND exp_channel_titles.status = 'open' 
  GROUP BY exp_categories.cat_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

edit: Adding the column you want to be distinct in the GROUP BY clause will ensure there's only 1 returned.  Also, the ORDER BY RAND() is heavily discouraged, see: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need you could close your query with:

```
GROUP BY exp_categories.cat_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're joining one-to-many, so you will see as many rows as there are records in the "many" table.  If you only want to bring back one row per category, you need to either only query categories or decide what criteria you want to use to choose single values from exp_category_posts.

One example option is to query for the most recent post in a category and join on that resultset instead of exp_category_posts.